# Differentiate $g(x)=\int_{h(x)}^{0}\sin(2t)\,\text{d}t$.

Tags: calculus, integration

Let $$g(x)=\int_{h(x)}^{0}\sin(2t)\,\text{d}t,$$
where $h(x)=\int_{x^4+1}^{e^x}\sqrt{u^2+5}\,\text{d}u.$

**My attempt**

First of all, notice that
\begin{align*} h'(x)&=\sqrt{e^{2x}+5}\cdot (e^x)'-\sqrt{(x^4+1)^2+5}\cdot (x^4+1)\\ &=e^x\sqrt{e^{2x}+5}-4x^3\sqrt{(x^4+1)^2+5}.\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}g'(x)&=-\sin(2h(x))\cdot h'(x)\\ &=-\sin(2h(x))\cdot \left (e^x\sqrt{e^{2x}+5}-4x^3\sqrt{(x^4+1)^2+5}\right )\\&=4x^3\cdot \sin(2h(x))\sqrt{(x^4+1)^2+5}-e^x\sin(2h(x))\cdot \sqrt{e^{2x}+5}. \end{align*}

Is my answer correct?

Comment: In my opinion it is correct.

Comment: Yes. that is fine.

Comment: Thanks, for help.